# Publish artefacts to two different SVN repositories in Hudson

Tags: svn, maven, hudson, hudson-plugins, repository

After the build, I want to **publish my artefacts** (jars) in **two different SVN repositories**, is it possible to do that in **Hudson**?

By using the Hudson plugin "Publish to Subversion repository", i can publish my artefacts **to only one SVN repository**!

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with publishing to a file repository.  Basically my work-around was to do post-task tasks which used command line scripts to transfer the files via ssh.

I suggest that you look into creating post-task tasks which submit your files to the svn repository via svn command line scripting.  It's a little more work, but it is far more flexible.

Comment: I want to avoid the use of the post build command or post-task tasks.

Comment: Note that i use actually post build step (delete svn then import svn).

Comment: Hudson has better support for doing multiple things before and during a build than in the artifact archiving stage.  That basically sucks, as there are use cases where multi-archive is common.  In my case, I post intermediate libraries (tagged to coordinate rev numbers) for larger projects to a central "in the lab" ssh accessible directory tree.  I also put them (again ssh transport) into a developer facing repository and a quality assurance facing repository.  From what I gathered, the archive step is not easily extensible for multiple archives.  You might find differently.  Good Luck.

Comment: Okay, so we should wait for a new release of the plugin "Publish to Subversion repository" that allows us to publish artefacts to multiple SVN repositories. Thank you.

Comment: It could be some wait.  If it really is critical, converting the archive tasks to regular build scripts (like suggested above) is an alternative.

Comment: Okay i'll try your proposition. Thank you.